# Android Application Error on background task only in Release Mode

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My App was running fine before i implemented mail sending feature. Still now in Debug works fine but when in Release it gives error. The task is to simply take info from controls and save them in MSSQL database.

***Background Process Calls:***

```
new CheckRegister(getActivity()).execute();
```

***Background Process Code:***

```
public class CheckRegister extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
    {
        String z="";
        Boolean isSuccess = false;
        private ProgressDialog dialog;

        public CheckRegister(Activity activity) {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            dialog.setMessage("Connecting to Server, please wait.");
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String r)
        {
            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }

            //Toast.makeText(getContext(), r, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if(isSuccess)
            {


                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("ImFromReg","Yes");
                startActivity(intent);
                getActivity().finish();                    

            }

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


            //Establish Connection
            Connection con = new GetConnection().connectionclass();
            if (con == null) {
                z="Error in Connection, Kindly Check your Internet!";
            }
            else
            {
                //Check already record exist!
                try {
                    String query = "My Query";
                    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                    if(rs.next())
                    {
                        // Record already exist
                        z="Provided Credentials Email/Cell  already registered!!!";
                        con.close();

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Start Register Process

                        CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall("{? =  call SP_YouRegisterInsert(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}");
                        cs.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
                        cs.setString(2,getDateTime());
                        cs.setString(3,vEmail.getText().toString().trim());
                        cs.setString(4,vCell.getText().toString().trim());
                        cs.setString(5,vName.getText().toString().trim());
                        cs.setString(6,vPassword.getText().toString().trim());

                        cs.setString(7,androidId);
                        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                        String vShortCode = "XYZ";
                        cs.setString(8,vShortCode);
                        ResultSet resS = cs.executeQuery();
                        int str=0;
                        if (resS.next()) {
                            str = resS.getInt(1);
                        }

                        // Save Settings
                        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext().getApplicationContext());
                        SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                        prefEditor.putString("email", vEmail.getText().toString().trim());                        
                        prefEditor.apply();


                        z = "Registration Completed."; // Your ID is:" + Integer.toString(str);
                        isSuccess=true;
                        con.close();



                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    z= ex.getMessage();
                }

            }
            return z;
        }
    }
```

***Error in Release Mode:***

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
    Process: com.panther.familyloco, PID: 31182
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.BlobImpl
        at g.a.a.a.J.a(:91)
        at g.a.a.a.J.<clinit>(:103)
        at g.a.a.a.h.a(:1515)
        at g.a.a.a.L.Q(:3285)
        at g.a.a.a.L.x(:2352)
        at g.a.a.a.L.a(:616)
        at g.a.a.a.h.<init>(:356)
        at g.a.a.a.l.connect(:188)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:179)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:144)
        at c.b.a.D.a(:35)
        at c.b.a.da$a.a(:286)
        at c.b.a.da$a.doInBackground(:241)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

***Dependencies:***

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation files('libs/jtds-1.2.7.jar')
implementation files('libs/mail.jar')
implementation files('libs/activation.jar')
implementation files('libs/additionnal.jar')
implementation files('libs\\ftp4j-1.7.2.jar')
```

I have tried many ways to trace the issue but can't figure out whats the problem. Applied log comments it shows app is crashing while creating connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be a issue related with obfuscation. Add the line `-keep class net.sourceforge.** { *; }` in `proguard-rules.pro` to avoid the obfuscation of all classes in package `net.sourceforge`and its sub packages.